# How to show that the sequence $x_n=\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n$ is convergent sequence and how to find the limit of $x_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have shown that the sequence is monotonically increasing but failed to show the sequence is bounded. How to show the sequence is bounded above ?

Comment: Looks like e$^2$

Comment: A slightly roundabout way (so I won't post it as an answer): one could argue that $\left(1 + \frac{2}{n}\right)^n < \left(1 + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n = \left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)^2$, and use any of a number of proofs that $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is bounded above. (A recent relevant thread is [Simple proof that $(1 + 1/n)^n$, $n \in \mathbb N$, is bounded above?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121354). It has quite specific requirements, but it alludes to proofs which can probably be easily found by searching in MSE.)

Comment: (Double take.) Actually, I'm puzzled by the second clause in the title of the question (not repeated in the question itself, which is why I failed to notice it). If one must find $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$, then (i) $e$ must be presumed known, and (ii) boundedness of the sequence $(x_n)$ follows from the fact that $(x_n)$ has a limit. I can't really make sense of this.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$\left( 1 + \frac{2}{n} \right)^n = \exp \left( n \ln \left( 1 + \frac{2}{n} \right) \right)$$

Then you can see that 
$$ n \ln \left( 1 + \frac{2}{n} \right)  \sim n \times \frac{2}{n} = 2$$

so this converges to $2$, and by composition, 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{2}{n} \right)^n = e^2$$